# Can we able to find face rotation (on left/right side) using ARCore Augmeted faces in Android?

Tags: android, arcore, face-detection, android-augmented-reality, google-mlkit

I am using [ARCore Augmented faces](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-faces) to create **Try-out-Jewellery App** in Android. I have created App which supports 3 different nose rings and 1 Mang Tikka (Head Jewellery). You can find reference video of our [Try-out-Jewellery App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yxTrHDIpvE) on youtube.

**ARCore augmented face mesh** is only covers points in front face and **not include points related to Ear part of face.**

I have also tried **[Google's ML Kit Face Detection API](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/face-detection-concepts)** to detect ear but I am **not able to use the 3d models files (.obj, .glb files)** there, it uses [Graphic Overlay](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/GraphicOverlay.java) to augmented image on face. I have tried to use Graphic overlay and Added bitmap to detected face elements using MLKit but it is not looking like real and also the overlay image has depth related issue.

I have 1 question based on above scenario of augmenting a ear ring.

1. Can we use **ML Kit Face detection API** such that it can **render the 3d model files with .glb, .obj extensions** ?

Below image is face mesh indices used in ARCore Augmented face API.
[image]

Comment: Speaking for ML Kit, the Face API currently only provides 2D landmarks, so I don't think it can help you here.

Comment: Hi, Pradip. I watch your youtube video. I wonder how you get 468 landmarks points using ARCore in ios/android. Can you please help me out to solve this issue?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68450636/how-to-get-468-face-landmarks-points-using-arcore-ios

Answer (score 0):

You can find the face rotation in augumented faces from the faceNode object.

```
faceNode.localRotation.x
```